# Flutter: Persistent item in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter

Currently I'm creating an application using Flutter which involves several lists which can be ordered and filtered. When an ordering or filter is active, persistent bar appears under the app bar which indicates what filters are active. This is achieved by stacking int on top of a `ListView` using a `StackView`, and moving the `ListView` down a little using it's padding. An example of this can be seen in the image below:

[image: Working app bar]

Now I'm trying to create a second view using a `CustomScrollView` and a `SliverAppBar`, and I want this same "filter bar" behaviour here. I've tried using a `SliverList` with a single item, and a `SliverList` below that with the filtered items, but then both lists scroll as if they were one long list. I've also tried adding a bar through the `bottom` property of the `SliverAppBar`, but this results in a bar which is placed over the title of the app bar, and as far as I know, there is no way to move this title up. This result can be seen in the image below (the red bar is a placeholder for the filter bar in the first image).

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this "persistent" bar effect in a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar`?

Comment: Have a Column that has your filter bar and your CustomScrollView ?

Comment: That's definitely a bug in flutter. Try to create an issue

Comment: @aziza that won't work. Because the title changes in size depending on the current scroll offset.

Comment: @Darky Thanks, didn’t know whether that was expected behavior or not, I’ll creatie an issue at Flutter

Comment: @Darky Looked at the flutter documentation, does seem to be expected behaviour: "If a flexibleSpace widget is specified then it is stacked behind the toolbar and the bottom widget."

Comment: @Dirk "bug" is not the best word. The problem is more that `FlexibleSpace` is kind of limited right now. You can't add leading nor actions buttons for example. Which is a _huge_ miss

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple scrollable views to be managed on the screen, you'll need to use [`NestedScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html). This should solve the issue where both scrollable widgets are scrolled like a single long list.

Here's a sample on how it can be implemented similar to the screenshots you've provided.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // This will help manage the SliverAppBar and ListView
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.jpeg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Title',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // title: const Text('Title'),
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 300.0,
              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                toolbarHeight: 64.0,
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Center(child: Text('Item $index')),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]